# Try to return string value from - ( void) captureoutput and then output it to a uitableview

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am doing this iOS exercise and trying to get the bar-code data which is stored in the NSString detectionString and output to the tableview. I have declared a @property NSString* detectionString but in my tableview method it is not coming up

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputMetadataObjects:(NSArray *)metadataObjects fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
    {
        CGRect highlightViewRect = CGRectZero;
        AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject *barCodeObject;
        NSString *detectionString = nil;
        NSArray *barCodeTypes = @[AVMetadataObjectTypeUPCECode, AVMetadataObjectTypeCode39Code, AVMetadataObjectTypeCode39Mod43Code,
                                  AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN13Code, AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN8Code, AVMetadataObjectTypeCode93Code, AVMetadataObjectTypeCode128Code,
                                  AVMetadataObjectTypePDF417Code, AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode, AVMetadataObjectTypeAztecCode];



        for (AVMetadataObject *metadata in metadataObjects) {
            for (NSString *type in barCodeTypes) {
                if ([metadata.type isEqualToString:type])
                {
                    barCodeObject = (AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject *)[_scanPreviewLayer transformedMetadataObjectForMetadataObject:(AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject *)metadata];
                    highlightViewRect = barCodeObject.bounds;

**// the string that contains the barcode data -->**                    self.detectionString = [(AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject *)metadata stringValue];

                    break;
                }
            }
            // Conditional statement to test if barcode was scanning

                if (detectionString != nil)
                {
                    _ScanLabel.text = detectionString;

                    break;
                }
                else
                    _ScanLabel.text = @"nil";

            }

            _ScanLaserCaptureView.frame = highlightViewRect;


    }


    - (NSString *)detectionString

    {   **//stored string value, I want to appear on my tableview method**
        return _detectionString;
    }
```

Comment: Please fix your code formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Once you get the detection string reload your table and to cells pass the detection string in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: I'm trying to load the NSString detectionString from the capture output method to my tableview but no matter what I do loads it, I've tried calling my AANScanViewController method:                                                             NSArray *items = [[NSArray alloc] init];                           AANScanViewController *selectedItem = items[indexPath.row];